# Rails 5 No route matches... fixes itself on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this problem has just recently (as of my last code push) started occurring on a page that has otherwise worked well for a year on this current server and rails version (5.0.0.1). I am getting the error below randomly, but a) the route does exist, and I use it all the time successfully, and b) if I refresh the page (sometimes takes a couple of times) then it loads. In other words, it seems like the failure to find the route is only temporary. Also, it only seems to happen after I return from a detail page (though this is not 100% verified). That is, I load a list page containing the below markup, then I click through to a detail page, then I click to return to the list, and get the error, on a page I was just on a moment ago! Has any one else experienced this? I am easily willing to believe I am doing something wrong, but not sure what to look at, since the routing is legit. 
Thanks in advance, 
Ian

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"membership_confirmation", :controller=>"members", :id=>488}):
19:         <% if p.member && @editable %>
20:           <%= link_to raw("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-usd\"></span>  Add Payment"), new_payment_path(:pid => p.id), :class => "btn btn-primary person-add-payment new msg-trigger", :title => "Record a payment" %>
21:           <% last_sent = p.member.membership_notice_sent_at ? '(last sent at ' + p.member.membership_notice_sent_at.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y') + ') ' : '' %>
22:           <%= link_to raw("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-envelope\"></span>  Memb. Letter"), {:controller => "members", :action => "membership_confirmation", :id => p.member.id}, {:class => "btn btn-primary ajaxify new msg-trigger", :title => "Send Confirmation #{last_sent}", :target => "_send", :data => {:confirm => "This will send an email message to #{p.email} #{last_sent}- do you want to continue?"}} %>
23:           <% last_sent = p.member.renewal_notice_sent_at ? '(last sent at ' + p.member.renewal_notice_sent_at.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y') + ') ' : '' %>
24:           <%= link_to raw("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-envelope\"></span>  Renewal Msg."), {:controller => "members", :action => "renewal_message", :id => p.member.id}, {:class => "btn btn-primary ajaxify new msg-trigger", :title => "Send Renewal Message #{last_sent}", :target => "_send", :data => {:confirm => "This will send an email message to #{p.email} #{last_sent}- do you want to continue?"}} %>
25:         <% else %>
app/views/people/_list.html.erb:22:
```

Here is the full _list.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped responsive-utilities">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Member No.</th>
      <th>Membership Status</th>
      <th>Expiration</th>
     <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% people.each do |p| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to p.full_name, {:controller => "people", :action =>@editable ? "edit" : "show", :id => p.id}, {:class => "btn btn-secondary new msg-trigger", :title => "#{p.email} ~ #{p.full_address(' ~ ')} ~ #{p.phone} ~ #{p.note}"} %></td>
      <td><%= p.member ? p.member.id.to_s.rjust(4, '0') : "" %></td>
      <td><%= p.membership_status() %></td>
      <td><%= p.member ? p.member.expires_at : "" %></th>
      <td>
        <% if p.member && @editable %>
          <%= link_to raw("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-usd\"></span>  Add Payment"), new_payment_path(:pid => p.id), :class => "btn btn-primary person-add-payment new msg-trigger", :title => "Record a payment" %>
      <% last_sent = p.member.membership_notice_sent_at ? '(last sent at ' + p.member.membership_notice_sent_at.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y') + ') ' : '' %>
          <%= link_to raw("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-envelope\"></span>  Memb. Letter"), {:controller => "members", :action => "membership_confirmation", :id => p.member.id}, {:class => "btn btn-primary ajaxify new msg-trigger", :title => "Send Confirmation #{last_sent}", :target => "_send", :data => {:confirm => "This will send an email message to #{p.email} #{last_sent}- do you want to continue?"}} %>
      <% last_sent = p.member.renewal_notice_sent_at ? '(last sent at ' + p.member.renewal_notice_sent_at.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y') + ') ' : '' %>
          <%= link_to raw("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-envelope\"></span>  Renewal Msg."), {:controller => "members", :action => "renewal_message", :id => p.member.id}, {:class => "btn btn-primary ajaxify new msg-trigger", :title => "Send Renewal Message #{last_sent}", :target => "_send", :data => {:confirm => "This will send an email message to #{p.email} #{last_sent}- do you want to continue?"}} %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to raw("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-user\"></span>  View"), {:controller => "people", :action => "show", :id => p.id}, {:class => "btn btn-primary", :title => "View Details"} %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="bja_pagination">
   <%= will_paginate people, :page_links => true %>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant section of routes.rb:

```
  get "members/renewal_message"
  get "members/membership_confirmation"
  resources :members
```

And here is the relevant output of rake routes:

```
            members_renewal_message GET    /members/renewal_message(.:format)                            members#renewal_message
        members_membership_confirmation GET    /members/membership_confirmation(.:format)                    members#membership_confirmation
                                members GET    /members(.:format)                                            members#index
                                        POST   /members(.:format)                                            members#create
                             new_member GET    /members/new(.:format)                                        members#new
                            edit_member GET    /members/:id/edit(.:format)                                   members#edit
                                 member GET    /members/:id(.:format)                                        members#show
                                        PATCH  /members/:id(.:format)                                        members#update
                                        PUT    /members/:id(.:format)                                        members#update
                                        DELETE /members/:id(.:format)                                        members#destroy
```

Comment: It depends of the exactly error message, but I guess it is related to an id not set, maybe `p.id` or `p.member.id`

Comment: Can you share your `routes.rb` around the `members` controller and the `membership_confirmation` action?

Comment: can you share list html and routes file.?

Comment: Thanks - I thought the resulting error contained all the relevant info, but just in case, I've added the full _list template, as well as the relevant portions of route.rb and the output of rake routes. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Argh, I'm an idiot. Of course, I was missing the :id on the route. I have no idea why it sometimes works and sometimes not - it seems like it should never work. But it's been plugging along like that for years!

--NOPE, turns out it still is an ongoing problem. No one has any ideas or similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
get "members/renewal_message", to: "members#renwal_message"
get "members/membership_confirmation", to: "members#membership_confirmation"
```

And then make sure you have those two methods "renwal_message" and "membership_confirmation" in your MembersController.